# Postfix send mail restrictions

Tags: postfix

I would like to setup my Postfix following way:

1. Allow to send email only by authenticated users on any email address (authentication is working now)
2. Allow to receive messages only to the limited number of users (preferrably specified in /etc/postfix/virtual, but I can add any other required file)

Actually I have only following restrictions in `main.cf`:

```
relayhost =
relay_domains = $mydestination
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks,reject_unauth_destination,permit
smtpd_sender_restrictions = permit_mynetworks,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject_non_fqdn_sender,reject_unknown_sender_domain,permit

virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual

alias_database = hash:/etc/postfix/aliases, hash:/etc/aliases
```

Content of `/etc/postfix/virtual` file aimed to collect all mail from specified virtual user to existing local one:

```
admin@mysite.com      postfix
feedback@mysite.com   postfix
abuse@mysite.com      postfix
webmaster@mysite.com  postfix
```

As I understand `smtpd_recipient_restrictions` value `reject_unauth_destination` should be enough, but when I turn it on I cannot send emails to any external system - postfix says `Relay access denied`. I cannot get how to fix it.

**UPD:** Finally I placed 'paranoid-style' record:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
        permit_mynetworks,
#       permit,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        reject
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you added `reject_unauth_destination` to `smtpd_recipient_restrictions`, did you remember/know that Postfix evaluates those values from left to right? If you put it

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unauth_destination,permit_sasl_authenticated...
```

it will reject everything.

Put it last on the list, it should work.

Comment: Nope, it still not working: I can send email from address "spam@spam.com" to any external address. I would not to be open for spammers.

Comment: Are you trying this from your localhost? permit_mynetworks makes everything allowed from your server itself, but if you try from some external address not contained in the allowed networks, it should fail as expected.

Comment: "it will reject everything." - you are wrong. postfix will receive mail for domains matches $mydestination, $inet_interfaces, $proxy_interfaces, $virtual_alias_domains or $virtual_mailbox_domains

Comment: @JannePikkarainen brilliant! I did not know about `permit_mynetworks` finally I removed this record also.

Answer (score 0):

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
        permit_sasl_authenticated,
#       permit_mynetworks,
#       permit,
        reject_unauth_destination,
        reject
```

It wouldn't work. Other mail servers will be unable send mail to you. You must at least add **permit_auth_destination**. I think the best solution would be the following

```
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
   permit_mynetworks,            
   permit_sasl_authenticated,
   permit_auth_destination,
   reject
```